# How optimize application speed + Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I have a windows application with 11 database with about 1.5 Gb text information.

I use SQL Server CE and Entity Framework.

My application has been finished, but for new version my application, it must run from DVD. Every part of application has a separate database.

Everything is fine, but first query of each database take about 40 sec to run. I searched a lot about this and I found these solutions:

1. pre-generate views to avoid the first time performance
2. get rid of linq, and rewrite it in ADO.NET
3. start by profiling the SQL commands actually issued by Entity Framework

and ...

I want to ask witch is the best way and fastest to do?

Comment: Step 0: Profile your application and find out what is slow.

Comment: It could be an issue of the database file having been created on one OS platform and the app running on another - are you using temp directory in your connection string?

Comment: @ErikEJ:yes i use temp directory

Comment: @SLaks: exactly  i profile it,my query is slow.

Comment: I think it could be index rebuild, what platform did you build the databases on, and what platform are you running?

Comment: @ErikEJ: Both of them windows.

Comment: Sure, but are you mixing XP/Server 2003 and 7/8 ?

Comment: @ErikEJ:No i just use win 7